# Низкий фпс на android в libgdx при отрисовке карты

Tags: java, android, kotlin, libgdx

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня есть карта в виде двумерного массива 1000x300 в ней записаны цифры ,означающие то,что нужно отрисовать 0 - пустота, 1 - земля ,2 - трава ..... и т.д.
Я рисую с помощью libgdx на spriteBatch (canvas)  ток часть массива по размеру экрана 1 клеточка = 24x24px SIZE = 24 ,если размеры экрана 1500x720 то я буду отрисовывть 1500/SIZEx720/SIZE
это примерно 63x30 [image: введите сюда описание изображения] но у меня при запуске на samsung m12 при 120 Ghz 30 фпс максимум а среднее значение в районе 20,при смене на 60Ghz максимум 40фпс а среднее в районе 28-32 фпс[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ,
естественно это мало.Я хотел бы 60фпс при 120Ghz и выше,была идея отрисовать эту карту полностью на отдельный спрайт а потом его рисовать на спрайтбатче,как это сделать и сможет ли это помочь?

```
   if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000) {
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fps = cadrs;
        cadrs = 0;
           Log.e("FPS",""+fps)
    } else {
        cadrs++;
    }


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    canvas!!.begin()
    var startI: Int =
            (floor(px / SIZE - Gdx.graphics.width / SIZE / 3) - 8).toInt();
        var endI: Int =
            floor(px / SIZE + Gdx.graphics.width / SIZE / 3 * 2.1).toInt();



        for (i in (startI)..(endI)) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= mapController.arr.size) {
            continue;
        }
        var startE: Int =
            floor(py / SIZE - Gdx.graphics.height / SIZE / 3 * 1.18 + 0.7).toInt()

        var endE: Int =
            (floor(py / SIZE + Gdx.graphics.height / SIZE / 3 * (hightTop + 0.7)) + 8).toInt()



        for (j in (startE)..(endE)) {


            if (j < 0 || j >= mapController.arr[0].size) {
                continue;
            }
          
            var posx: Float =
                (i * size - px + (Gdx.graphics.width / 3))

            var posy: Float =
                (py * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop).toFloat();

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 2 || mapController.arr[i][j] == 1) {
                 if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 2) {

                    if (i > 0 && mapController.arr[i - 1][j] == 2 && mapController.arr[i][j - 1] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (1 + i < mapController.arr.size && mapController.arr[i + 1][j] == 2 && mapController.arr[i][j - 1] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (mapController.arr[i][j + 1] == 2 && i + 1 < mapController.arr.size && mapController.arr[i + 1][j] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_left,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (mapController.arr[i][j + 1] == 2 && j + 1 < mapController.arr[0].size && mapController.arr[i - 1][j] == 2 && i > 0) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_right,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else {

                        //   data.drawImage()
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        );
                        // data.drawImage(image_grass_piece,0,0,image_grass_piece.width,image_grass_piece.height,i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)
                        // data.drawImage(image_grass, 19, 0, 14, 15, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)
                    }
                }


                if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 1) {

                    // console.log(g)

                    // data.drawImage(image_ground_piece, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop);

                    //  image_ground_piece
                    draw(
                        image_ground_tile,
                        (posx),
                        (posy)
                    )


                }


            }

            var opx: Float =
                posx;
            var opy: Float =
                posy;

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 3) {
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                draw(
                    image_glizinia,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
                // data.drawImage(image_glizinia, 0, 0, image_glizinia.width, image_glizinia.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3-image_glizinia.width/2/dt, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 9) {
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                draw(
                    image_glizinia2,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6.5 / dt).toFloat()
                );

                //data.drawImage(image_glizinia2, 0, 0, image_glizinia2.width, image_glizinia2.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6.5 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 8) {
                // data.fillStyle = "#000000"
                //data.fillRect( i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)

                draw(
                    image_trees,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                //data.drawImage(image_trees, 0, 0, image_trees.width, image_trees.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3-image_trees.width/2/dt, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }


            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 200) {

                draw(image_coin, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 4) {


                draw(image_health, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 5) {

                draw(image_power, posx, posy)

            }

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 6) {

                draw(image_amor, posx, posy)

            }


            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 7) {
                //  console.log("nitro")
                draw(image_nitro, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 11) {
                draw(
                    image_house1,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 7 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 12) {
                draw(
                    image_house2,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 13) {
                draw(
                    image_house3,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 7 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }


            for (entry in mapController.npcMap.entries.iterator()) {
                // print("${entry.key} : ${entry.value}")
                //entry.value.draw(data)
            }

            if ( this.player != null && this.player.animate != null) {

                var ww = 160 / 1.3;
                var hh = 120 / 1.3;
                var top = 0;
                if (this.player.type == 50 && images.get1(this.player.id + "_stay_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(this.player.id + "_stay_top");
                }
                if (this.player.type == 51 && images.get1(this.player.id + "_run_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(this.player.id + "_run_top");
                }
                //for (l in 0..20 - 1) {
                //   if (this.player.type == l) {
                //if (images.get1(this.player.id + "_" + l + "_top") != null)
                //      top = images.get1(this.player.id + "_" + l + "_top")
                //  }
                // }
                
                if(animate!=null){

                    var playerX = Gdx.graphics.width / 3 - ((ww - player.w) / 2 / dt)
                    var playerY = Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt
                   /* draw(
                        player.animate,
                        (playerX).toFloat(),
                        (playerY).toFloat(),
                        paint    )

                    */



                }
              


            }
            for (i in 0..mapController.anotherPlayers.size-1) {
                var enemy_player = this.mapController.anotherPlayers[i];
                if (enemy_player.animate == null) continue;



                //data.fillRect(this.posx - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.posy - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, this.sizeX / dt, this.sizeY / dt);
                var ppx = enemy_player.position.x - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3;
                var ppy = enemy_player.position.y - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop;
                //  data.fillStyle = "#ff0101"
                //console.log(enemy_player.idPlayer+" "+(enemy_player.position.x - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3)+";"+(enemy_player.position.y - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop));
                // data.fillRect(enemy_player.position.x - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, enemy_player.position.y - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, enemy_player.w / dt, enemy_player.h / dt);

                //data.fillRect(posx, posy, 32 / dt, 48 / dt);

                //  if(this.lll !=0){
                if (enemy_player.side == 1) {
                    //    data.save()
                    //     data.scale(-1, 1)

                    //  data.translate(-example.width - (example.width - (example.width - ppx) * 2) - enemy_player.w / 3 * 2 / dt, 0);
                    // console.log((example.width-(example.width-ppx)*2))
                    //console.log(-example.width+ppx)
                    //if(ppx<0 ||ppx>window.innerWidth)return;
                    // if(ppy<0 ||ppy>window.innerHeight)return;

                    //  ctx.translate(-example.width+ppx, 0)
                    //  this.lll=0;
                }
                //}
                var ww = 160 / 1.3;
                var hh = 120 / 1.3;
                var top = 0;

                if (enemy_player.type == 50 && images.get(enemy_player.id + "_stay_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(enemy_player.id + "_stay_top")
                }
                if (enemy_player.type == 51 && images.get(enemy_player.id + "_run_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(enemy_player.id + "_run_top")
                }



                for (l in 0..20) {
                    if (enemy_player.type == l) {
                        if (images.get(enemy_player.id + "_" + l + "_top") != null)
                            top = images.get1(enemy_player.id + "_" + l + "_top")
                    }
                }

                // data.drawImage(this.player.animate, 0, 0, this.player.animate.width, this.player.animate.height, Gdx.graphics.width / 3 - ((ww - player.w) / 2 / dt), Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt, ww / dt, hh / dt)

                // data.drawImage(enemy_player.animate, 0, 0, enemy_player.animate.width, enemy_player.animate.height, ppx - ((ww - enemy_player.w + 15) / 2 / dt), ppy - (hh - enemy_player.h + 12) / dt, ww / dt, hh / dt)
               // draw(enemy_player.animate,  (ppx - ((ww - enemy_player.w) / 2 / dt)).toFloat(), (ppy - top / dt).toFloat(),null)

                if (enemy_player.side == 1) {
                    // data.scale(-1, 1)

                    //  ctx.translate(ppx, 0)

                    // ctx.translate(example.width, 0)
                    //    data.restore();
                }






                // data.drawImage(enemy_player.animate, 0, 0, enemy_player.animate.width, enemy_player.animate.height, Gdx.graphics.width / 3 - ((ww - enemy_player.w) / 2 / dt), Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt, ww / dt, hh / dt)





                // data.drawImage(this.player.animate_shot, Gdx.graphics.width / 3 + this.player.animate_shot.width - ((ww - player.w) / 2 / dt), Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt)






                /*if (this.player.side == 1) {
                    data.scale(-1, 1)

                    ctx.translate(Gdx.graphics.width / 3 * 2 + player.w / dt, 0)
                    data.restore();
                }
                */

            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял ,в методе отрисовки я пробегался по массиву 63х30 и за один раз я отрисовывал 1869 раз игрока и врагов,я просто вынес отрисовку игрока и врагов за пределы циклов

```
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000) {
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fps = cadrs;
        cadrs = 0;
           Log.e("FPS",""+fps)
    } else {
        cadrs++;
    }


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    canvas!!.begin()
    var startI: Int =
            (floor(px / SIZE - Gdx.graphics.width / SIZE / 3) - 8).toInt();
        var endI: Int =
            floor(px / SIZE + Gdx.graphics.width / SIZE / 3 * 2.1).toInt();



        for (i in (startI)..(endI)) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= mapController.arr.size) {
            continue;
        }
        var startE: Int =
            floor(py / SIZE - Gdx.graphics.height / SIZE / 3 * 1.18 + 0.7).toInt()

        var endE: Int =
            (floor(py / SIZE + Gdx.graphics.height / SIZE / 3 * (hightTop + 0.7)) + 8).toInt()



        for (j in (startE)..(endE)) {


            if (j < 0 || j >= mapController.arr[0].size) {
                continue;
            }
          
            var posx: Float =
                (i * size - px + (Gdx.graphics.width / 3))

            var posy: Float =
                (py * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop).toFloat();

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 2 || mapController.arr[i][j] == 1) {
                 if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 2) {

                    if (i > 0 && mapController.arr[i - 1][j] == 2 && mapController.arr[i][j - 1] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (1 + i < mapController.arr.size && mapController.arr[i + 1][j] == 2 && mapController.arr[i][j - 1] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (mapController.arr[i][j + 1] == 2 && i + 1 < mapController.arr.size && mapController.arr[i + 1][j] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_left,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (mapController.arr[i][j + 1] == 2 && j + 1 < mapController.arr[0].size && mapController.arr[i - 1][j] == 2 && i > 0) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_right,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else {

                        //   data.drawImage()
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        );
                        // data.drawImage(image_grass_piece,0,0,image_grass_piece.width,image_grass_piece.height,i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)
                        // data.drawImage(image_grass, 19, 0, 14, 15, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)
                    }
                }


                if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 1) {

                    // console.log(g)

                    // data.drawImage(image_ground_piece, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop);

                    //  image_ground_piece
                    draw(
                        image_ground_tile,
                        (posx),
                        (posy)
                    )


                }


            }
//код который вынес - отрисовка врагов и игрока
            var opx: Float =
                posx;
            var opy: Float =
                posy;

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 3) {
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                draw(
                    image_glizinia,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
                // data.drawImage(image_glizinia, 0, 0, image_glizinia.width, image_glizinia.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3-image_glizinia.width/2/dt, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 9) {
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                draw(
                    image_glizinia2,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6.5 / dt).toFloat()
                );

                //data.drawImage(image_glizinia2, 0, 0, image_glizinia2.width, image_glizinia2.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6.5 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 8) {
                // data.fillStyle = "#000000"
                //data.fillRect( i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)

                draw(
                    image_trees,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                //data.drawImage(image_trees, 0, 0, image_trees.width, image_trees.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3-image_trees.width/2/dt, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }


            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 200) {

                draw(image_coin, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 4) {


                draw(image_health, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 5) {

                draw(image_power, posx, posy)

            }

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 6) {

                draw(image_amor, posx, posy)

            }


            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 7) {
                //  console.log("nitro")
                draw(image_nitro, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 11) {
                draw(
                    image_house1,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 7 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 12) {
                draw(
                    image_house2,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 13) {
                draw(
                    image_house3,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 7 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }


            


        }
    }
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000) {
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fps = cadrs;
        cadrs = 0;
           Log.e("FPS",""+fps)
    } else {
        cadrs++;
    }


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    canvas!!.begin()
    var startI: Int =
            (floor(px / SIZE - Gdx.graphics.width / SIZE / 3) - 8).toInt();
        var endI: Int =
            floor(px / SIZE + Gdx.graphics.width / SIZE / 3 * 2.1).toInt();



        for (i in (startI)..(endI)) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= mapController.arr.size) {
            continue;
        }
        var startE: Int =
            floor(py / SIZE - Gdx.graphics.height / SIZE / 3 * 1.18 + 0.7).toInt()

        var endE: Int =
            (floor(py / SIZE + Gdx.graphics.height / SIZE / 3 * (hightTop + 0.7)) + 8).toInt()



        for (j in (startE)..(endE)) {


            if (j < 0 || j >= mapController.arr[0].size) {
                continue;
            }
          
            var posx: Float =
                (i * size - px + (Gdx.graphics.width / 3))

            var posy: Float =
                (py * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop).toFloat();

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 2 || mapController.arr[i][j] == 1) {
                 if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 2) {

                    if (i > 0 && mapController.arr[i - 1][j] == 2 && mapController.arr[i][j - 1] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (1 + i < mapController.arr.size && mapController.arr[i + 1][j] == 2 && mapController.arr[i][j - 1] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (mapController.arr[i][j + 1] == 2 && i + 1 < mapController.arr.size && mapController.arr[i + 1][j] == 2) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_left,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else if (mapController.arr[i][j + 1] == 2 && j + 1 < mapController.arr[0].size && mapController.arr[i - 1][j] == 2 && i > 0) {
                        draw(
                            image_grass_right,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        )

                    } else {

                        //   data.drawImage()
                        draw(
                            image_grass_piece,
                            posx,
                            posy
                        );
                        // data.drawImage(image_grass_piece,0,0,image_grass_piece.width,image_grass_piece.height,i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)
                        // data.drawImage(image_grass, 19, 0, 14, 15, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)
                    }
                }


                if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 1) {

                    // console.log(g)

                    // data.drawImage(image_ground_piece, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop);

                    //  image_ground_piece
                    draw(
                        image_ground_tile,
                        (posx),
                        (posy)
                    )


                }


            }

            var opx: Float =
                posx;
            var opy: Float =
                posy;

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 3) {
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                draw(
                    image_glizinia,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
                // data.drawImage(image_glizinia, 0, 0, image_glizinia.width, image_glizinia.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3-image_glizinia.width/2/dt, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 9) {
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                draw(
                    image_glizinia2,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6.5 / dt).toFloat()
                );

                //data.drawImage(image_glizinia2, 0, 0, image_glizinia2.width, image_glizinia2.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6.5 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 8) {
                // data.fillStyle = "#000000"
                //data.fillRect( i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, SIZE, SIZE)

                draw(
                    image_trees,
                    opx.toFloat(),
                    (opy - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
                //  console.log("glizinia ...")
                //data.drawImage(image_trees, 0, 0, image_trees.width, image_trees.height, i * size - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3-image_trees.width/2/dt, this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt, START_SIZE * 8 / dt);
            }


            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 200) {

                draw(image_coin, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 4) {


                draw(image_health, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 5) {

                draw(image_power, posx, posy)

            }

            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 6) {

                draw(image_amor, posx, posy)

            }


            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 7) {
                //  console.log("nitro")
                draw(image_nitro, posx, posy)

            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 11) {
                draw(
                    image_house1,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 7 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 12) {
                draw(
                    image_house2,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 6 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }
            if (mapController.arr[i][j] == 13) {
                draw(
                    image_house3,
                    posx,
                    (this.player.position.y * -1 + j * size + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - START_SIZE * 7 / dt).toFloat()
                )
            }


            


        }
    }
    for (entry in mapController.npcMap.entries.iterator()) {
                // print("${entry.key} : ${entry.value}")
                //entry.value.draw(data)
            }

            if ( this.player != null && this.player.animate != null) {

                var ww = 160 / 1.3;
                var hh = 120 / 1.3;
                var top = 0;
                if (this.player.type == 50 && images.get1(this.player.id + "_stay_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(this.player.id + "_stay_top");
                }
                if (this.player.type == 51 && images.get1(this.player.id + "_run_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(this.player.id + "_run_top");
                }
                //for (l in 0..20 - 1) {
                //   if (this.player.type == l) {
                //if (images.get1(this.player.id + "_" + l + "_top") != null)
                //      top = images.get1(this.player.id + "_" + l + "_top")
                //  }
                // }
                
                if(animate!=null){

                    var playerX = Gdx.graphics.width / 3 - ((ww - player.w) / 2 / dt)
                    var playerY = Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt
                   /* draw(
                        player.animate,
                        (playerX).toFloat(),
                        (playerY).toFloat(),
                        paint    )

                    */



                }
              


            }
            for (i in 0..mapController.anotherPlayers.size-1) {
                var enemy_player = this.mapController.anotherPlayers[i];
                if (enemy_player.animate == null) continue;



                //data.fillRect(this.posx - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, this.posy - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, this.sizeX / dt, this.sizeY / dt);
                var ppx = enemy_player.position.x - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3;
                var ppy = enemy_player.position.y - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop;
                //  data.fillStyle = "#ff0101"
                //console.log(enemy_player.idPlayer+" "+(enemy_player.position.x - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3)+";"+(enemy_player.position.y - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop));
                // data.fillRect(enemy_player.position.x - this.player.position.x + Gdx.graphics.width / 3, enemy_player.position.y - this.player.position.y + Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop, enemy_player.w / dt, enemy_player.h / dt);

                //data.fillRect(posx, posy, 32 / dt, 48 / dt);

                //  if(this.lll !=0){
                if (enemy_player.side == 1) {
                    //    data.save()
                    //     data.scale(-1, 1)

                    //  data.translate(-example.width - (example.width - (example.width - ppx) * 2) - enemy_player.w / 3 * 2 / dt, 0);
                    // console.log((example.width-(example.width-ppx)*2))
                    //console.log(-example.width+ppx)
                    //if(ppx<0 ||ppx>window.innerWidth)return;
                    // if(ppy<0 ||ppy>window.innerHeight)return;

                    //  ctx.translate(-example.width+ppx, 0)
                    //  this.lll=0;
                }
                //}
                var ww = 160 / 1.3;
                var hh = 120 / 1.3;
                var top = 0;

                if (enemy_player.type == 50 && images.get(enemy_player.id + "_stay_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(enemy_player.id + "_stay_top")
                }
                if (enemy_player.type == 51 && images.get(enemy_player.id + "_run_top") != null) {
                    top = images.get1(enemy_player.id + "_run_top")
                }



                for (l in 0..20) {
                    if (enemy_player.type == l) {
                        if (images.get(enemy_player.id + "_" + l + "_top") != null)
                            top = images.get1(enemy_player.id + "_" + l + "_top")
                    }
                }

                // data.drawImage(this.player.animate, 0, 0, this.player.animate.width, this.player.animate.height, Gdx.graphics.width / 3 - ((ww - player.w) / 2 / dt), Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt, ww / dt, hh / dt)

                // data.drawImage(enemy_player.animate, 0, 0, enemy_player.animate.width, enemy_player.animate.height, ppx - ((ww - enemy_player.w + 15) / 2 / dt), ppy - (hh - enemy_player.h + 12) / dt, ww / dt, hh / dt)
               // draw(enemy_player.animate,  (ppx - ((ww - enemy_player.w) / 2 / dt)).toFloat(), (ppy - top / dt).toFloat(),null)

                if (enemy_player.side == 1) {
                    // data.scale(-1, 1)

                    //  ctx.translate(ppx, 0)

                    // ctx.translate(example.width, 0)
                    //    data.restore();
                }






                // data.drawImage(enemy_player.animate, 0, 0, enemy_player.animate.width, enemy_player.animate.height, Gdx.graphics.width / 3 - ((ww - enemy_player.w) / 2 / dt), Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt, ww / dt, hh / dt)





                // data.drawImage(this.player.animate_shot, Gdx.graphics.width / 3 + this.player.animate_shot.width - ((ww - player.w) / 2 / dt), Gdx.graphics.height / 3 * hightTop - top / dt)






                /*if (this.player.side == 1) {
                    data.scale(-1, 1)

                    ctx.translate(Gdx.graphics.width / 3 * 2 + player.w / dt, 0)
                    data.restore();
                }
                */

            }
```